# R scales::label_format is converting my numeric into a float before converting to character

Tags: r, format

I have a function that is designed to create labels for a graph. I have four data subsets that all come from the same source. My function works on three out of four subsets but is getting messed up on the fourth. I have a whole number (ie 2914). Scales::label_comma() converts the number 2914 to a character that reads "2914.0".

Here is a break down of the table that doesn't work:

```
    > str(df_a)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   9 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ year               : num  2017 2017 2017 2017 2018 ...
 $ inpatient_discharge: num  2914 2662 2566 2513 2672 ...
 $ ed_discharges      : num  23225 24117 24565 23001 24005 ...
 $ outpatient_surg    : num  3193 3313 2813 4255 3391 ...
>
```

And when I use label_comma() on the column "inpatient_discharge" which is numeric I get:

```
> scales::label_comma()(df_a$inpatient_discharge)
[1] "2,914.0" "2,662.0" "2,566.0" "2,513.0" "2,672.0" "2,478.0" "2,404.0" "2,398.0" "2,504.0"
```

When I use label_comma() on a different column, I get the expected result

```
> scales::label_comma()(df_a$ed_discharges)
[1] "23,225" "24,117" "24,565" "23,001" "24,005" "23,416" "23,983" "22,648" "23,390"
```

Furthermore, when I use label_comma() on a different dataframe that has a subset from the same source, I get the expected result

```
> scales::label_comma()(df_b$inpatient_discharge)
[1] "7,457" "7,066" "6,918" "6,912" "7,265" "6,918" "6,748" "6,733" "7,064"
```

Is this a bug? I can't find anything on why it would act this way. It even works on those numbers when they are outside of the dataframe

```
> test <- as.numeric(2914)
> label_comma()(test)
[1] "2,914"
```

I'm completely lost on this one

Comment: Can you convert to `integer` as.integer and then try `scales::label_comma()(as.integer(df_a$inpatient_discharge))`

Comment: `> scales::label_comma()(as.integer(df_a$inpatient_discharge))
[1] "2,914.0" "2,662.0" "2,566.0" "2,513.0" "2,672.0" "2,478.0" "2,404.0" "2,398.0" "2,504.0" ` It gave me the same result

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce.  Please show a small example with `dput` `scales::label_comma()(as.integer(c(2010, 2010.5, 2011.2)))#
[1] "2,010" "2,010" "2,011"`

Comment: @CMH89 if my answer below helped you answer your question, please tick it as accepted - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Quick fix

You can achieve this by passing the `accuracy` argument to `label_comma`.

`accuracy = 1` will ensure that no numbers past the decimal point are shown.

### Attempt at explanation

There must be something in your series of numbers that is convincing `label_comma` that it needs to use tenths to distinguish some of the numbers. See [the documentation](https://scales.r-lib.org/reference/label_number.html):

> **accuracy**: ... If NULL, the default, uses a heuristic that should ensure breaks have the minimum number of digits needed to show the difference between adjacent values.

This explains why your test example doesn't respond in the same way as your original df: it doesn't trigger the distinguishing heuristic.

### Examples of how to do it

Here's a reprex which gives a variety of ways of transforming your series of numbers into comma-formatted strings without the post-decimal point numbers. Obviously you don't need all of them but I was just testing what happens in different situations.

I have only used your first five numbers as visible in your question. In future please try to make [reproducible examples](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) - I usually find that this process leads me to the solution to my problem before I even have to ask!

You can insert your fuller number series into the example below, and see what happens.

The first few examples below don't use the `accuracy` argument; the last couple of examples do. But in all cases there are no post-decimal point numbers.

The final example replaces your original first column with formatted numbers (as strings) - this is how I would prefer to do this operation but you can choose what works for you.

```r
library(scales)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df <- tibble(inpatient_discharge = c(2914, 2662, 2566, 2513, 2672))
str(df)
#> Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    5 obs. of  1 variable:
#>  $ inpatient_discharge: num  2914 2662 2566 2513 2672

# add column using label_comma
df["discharge_label_comma"] <- scales::label_comma()(df[[1]])
str(df)
#> Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    5 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ inpatient_discharge  : num  2914 2662 2566 2513 2672
#>  $ discharge_label_comma: chr  "2,914" "2,662" "2,566" "2,513" ...

# add column using comma alias
df["discharge_comma"] <- scales::comma(df[[1]])
str(df)
#> Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    5 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ inpatient_discharge  : num  2914 2662 2566 2513 2672
#>  $ discharge_label_comma: chr  "2,914" "2,662" "2,566" "2,513" ...
#>  $ discharge_comma      : chr  "2,914" "2,662" "2,566" "2,513" ...

# add column using dplyr::mutate
df <- df %>% dplyr::mutate(discharge_comma_mutate = scales::comma(inpatient_discharge))
str(df)
#> Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    5 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ inpatient_discharge   : num  2914 2662 2566 2513 2672
#>  $ discharge_label_comma : chr  "2,914" "2,662" "2,566" "2,513" ...
#>  $ discharge_comma       : chr  "2,914" "2,662" "2,566" "2,513" ...
#>  $ discharge_comma_mutate: chr  "2,914" "2,662" "2,566" "2,513" ...

# add column using accuracy argument
df["discharge_comma_acc"] <- scales::comma(df[[1]], accuracy = 1)
str(df)
#> Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    5 obs. of  5 variables:
#>  $ inpatient_discharge   : num  2914 2662 2566 2513 2672
#>  $ discharge_label_comma : chr  "2,914" "2,662" "2,566" "2,513" ...
#>  $ discharge_comma       : chr  "2,914" "2,662" "2,566" "2,513" ...
#>  $ discharge_comma_mutate: chr  "2,914" "2,662" "2,566" "2,513" ...
#>  $ discharge_comma_acc   : chr  "2,914" "2,662" "2,566" "2,513" ...

# convert initial first column using dplyr::mutate_at and accuracy argument
# (alternatively use dplyr::transmute or mutate_all/mutate_if)
df <- df %>% mutate_at(vars(inpatient_discharge), ~ scales::comma(., accuracy = 1))
str(df)
#> Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    5 obs. of  5 variables:
#>  $ inpatient_discharge   : chr  "2,914" "2,662" "2,566" "2,513" ...
#>  $ discharge_label_comma : chr  "2,914" "2,662" "2,566" "2,513" ...
#>  $ discharge_comma       : chr  "2,914" "2,662" "2,566" "2,513" ...
#>  $ discharge_comma_mutate: chr  "2,914" "2,662" "2,566" "2,513" ...
#>  $ discharge_comma_acc   : chr  "2,914" "2,662" "2,566" "2,513" ...
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>